# Different Badminton Grip and Weight Types

Tags: equipment, badminton, racket

Over the years I've used many badminton rackets, with a wide variety of code numbering placed at the beginning of the shaft:

> G4/3U
>   G2/2U

Can somebody give me detailed information about the meaning of those codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE:** There appears to be no universal, consistent standard for these codes as codes for a manufacturer/country may represent opposite meanings compared to another manufacturer/country.

**G** is in reference to grip sizes.

**U** is in reference to racket weight.

For a *majority*<sub>([1](http://www.badminton-information.com/badminton_rackets.html))</sub> of rackets:

- [Grip sizes](http://www.badmintoncentral.com/forums/showthread.php/21340-Table-of-Badminton-Grip-Sizes) range from **G1**, **G2**, **G3**, **G4**, and **G5**

  - **G1** - 3 in (smallest)
  - **G2** - 3 1/4 in
  - **G3** - 3 1/2 in
  - **G4** - 3 3/4 in
  - **G5** - 4 in (largest)

> In Japan, they range from G2, G3, G4 to G5 where G2 is the biggest
>   size and G5 is the smallest size. In some countries, the opposite
>   applies.

- Racket weight ranges from **1U**, **2U**, **3U**, and **4U**

  - **1U** - up to 100 grams (heaviest)
  - **4U** - at least 70 grams (lightest)

Comment: Thanks for responding so quick. Can you narrow down the G codes to particular widths or the U codes for that matter?

Comment: Done...but with a note. Seems like Japan and some other countries are opposite when it comes to grip sizes...

Comment: Are the weights and the sizes measured with or without the grip?