# Badminton Racket Specifications

Tags: rules, equipment, badminton, racket

I've been playing with numerous badminton rackets:

- short
- long
- large blade
- long shaft

but are there exact badminton racket specifications regarding length and/or weight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [Badminton World Federation (BWF)](http://bwfbadminton.org/default.aspx) website, there are a lot of official documents to be found.

You need to go to the second tab (Organisation) on the main site and choose **Law & Regulations**.
After that you need to click on **Laws of Badminton** (circled red):

[image]

The document, titled: *[PART II, SECTION 1 A, LAWS OF BADMINTON](http://bwfbadminton.org/file_download.aspx?id=422701&tid=1)*, elaborates in chapter 4 on the racket specifications:

> **4.1**
>
> The racket shall be a frame not exceeding 680 mm in overall length and 230
>   mm in overall width consisting of the main parts described in Laws 4.1.1 to
>   4.1.5 as illustrated in Diagram C.

After that, in paragraph 2 of chapter 4, the following is explicitly mentioned  about the racket:

> **4.2 The stringed area:**
>
> **4.2.1**
>
> shall not exceed 280 mm in overall length and 220 mm in overall width. However, the strings may extend into an area which otherwise would be the throat, provided that:
>
> **4.2.2.1**
>
> the width of the extended stringed area does not exceed 35 mm; and
>
> **4.2.2.2**
>
> the overall length of the stringed area does not then exceed 330 mm

The weight isn't specified, thus out of bounds.

Answer (score -1):

**Badminton Rackets**

> Modern Badminton Rackets are light in weight and usually below 100
>   grams. The frame of the Racket can be made of steel, aluminum, carbon
>   fiber, ceramic, boron or a combination of some of these.
>
> It shall not exceed 680mm in overall length and 230 mm in overall
>   width.
>
> The weight should not exceed more than 100 grams.
>
> A majority of racket manufacturers use 1U, 2U, 3U, 4U to indicate the
>   weight of the racket, 1U being the heaviest and 4U the lightest. The
>   weight of high quality rackets range from 83 grams to 100 grams.

2U - 90 to 94g

3U - 85 to 89g

4U - 80 to 84g

The racket head may be either oval or square.

**Strings**:

> Badminton strings are thin, high performing strings in the range of
>   about 0.62 to 0.73 mm thickness. Thicker strings are more durable, but
>   many players prefer the feel of thinner strings. String tension is
>   normally in the range of 80 to 160 N (18 to 36 lbf). Recreational
>   players generally string at lower tensions than professionals,
>   typically between 80 and 110 N (18 and 25 lbf). Professionals string
>   between about 110 and 160 N (25 and 36 lbf). Some string manufacturers
>   measure the thickness of their strings under tension so they are
>   actually thicker then than specified when slack. Ashaway Micropower is
>   actually 0.7mm but Yonex BG-66 is about 0.72mm.

**Grip:**

> There are two main types of grip: replacement grips and overgrips.
>   Replacement grips are thicker, and are often used to increase the size
>   of the handle. Overgrips are thinner (less than 1 mm), and are often
>   used as the final layer. Many players, however, prefer to use
>   replacement grips as the final layer.
>
> Most racket manufacturers provide four grip sizes. In Japan, they
>   range from G2, G3, G4 to G5 where G2 is the biggest size and G5 is the
>   smallest size. In some countries, the opposite applies. Some brands go by small, medium and big sizes.

Hi-Qua / Tactic G2 - 3.25 inches,       Yonex G2 - 4.00 inches

Hi-Qua / Tactic G3 - 3.50 inches,       Yonex G3 - 3.75 inches

Hi-Qua / Tactic G4 - 3.75 inches,       Yonex G4 - 3.50 inches

Hi-Qua / Tactic G5 - 4.00 inches,       Yonex G5 - 3.25 inches

For more info about the terms G and U refer [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2766/753).

Source : [Badminton information.com](http://www.badminton-information.com/badminton_rackets.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badminton).

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked more precise, but I was looking for dimensions, like long, short. Actually the first three sentences would suffice. Can you add specific references for that?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, references were already added in the answer

Comment: You just copied the complete content into this answer. Where is the reference that `It shall not exceed 680mm in overall length and 230 mm in overall width`?

Comment: -1 Please refrain from copying content wholesale and use (block) quotes when not using your original work. See [this](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/223/527) for more info.